# Run script database when installing clickonce application

Tags: c#, mysql, database, installation, clickonce

I looked for an answer for my problem but either I didn't find it or I didn't understand the solutions.

I'm developing an Winforms application with C# that uses a MySQL database to store information. There is only a database per LAN. What I want is to give the customers the ability to install automatically MySQL server, the application database, and the application.

I don't mind if MySQL server and the database are together in a single installer or the 3 things are together (in that case, the installer should ask the user if they want to install MySQL and the database). Right now I'm using ClickOnce to publish the application.

How can I create an installer with those 3 things?

Thank you!

Comment: ClickOnce is most suitable for client application installations. I have never used it for server application deployment.

Comment: It is a client application, but I want to allow users to install the database since it will be in the first PC that installs the application. That means that one PC will access locally to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a bootstrapper is used to install third party apps when you are installing your application. Most [commercial products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer#Tools) offer this support, but you can also use free tools, recommended is [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/).